# c# user enter 2 dimension array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

```
    private void button_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int data = Convert.ToInt32(data_textBox.Text);

        if (radioButton_2.Checked == true)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < Array2d.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < Array2d.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Array2d[i,j] = data;
                }
            }
        }
        data_textBox.Clear();
    }
```

I want to fill the array what I enter the value each time not same value but code just last entered value filling all array element.

When I click add button it just do last entered value in the array. How do I fix it?

[image: ui]

Comment: Please provide a sample string.

Comment: What do you want to be fixed here? Do you realize that this code sets the same value to every single element of the array? If you don't explain well what is your goal then your question is at risk of closure as unclear what are you asking

Comment: i want to fill the array what i enter the value each time not same value  but code  just last entered value filling all array element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to have the user enter all the values in a multiline text box, separated by spaces and returns. The the program parses the text to create an array.

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int[,] array2d;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.array2d=ParseArray(textBox1.Lines, 4, 4);
    }
    public static int[,] ParseArray(string[] lines, int rows, int columns)
    {
        // allocate empty array
        var array=new int[rows, columns];
        // for each row of text
        for (int row=0; row<rows; row++)
        {
            // split into values separated by spaces, tabs, commas, or semicolons
            var items=lines[row].Split(',', ' ', ';', '\t');
            // for each value in the row
            for (int col=0; col<columns; col++)
            {
                // parse the string into an integer _safely_
                int x=0;
                int.TryParse(items[col], out x);
                array[row, col]=x;
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    public static int[,] ParseArray(string text, int rows, int columns)
    {
        // split text into lines
        var lines=text.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return ParseArray(lines, rows, columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no error checking in the code. If the user enters less numbers than expected it is going to fail. Also for doing math, it is usually faster and easier to use jagged arrays (`int[][]` types) instead of 2d arrays.